# Putting full background for particular Header cells in react-table ? Using getCellProps or not?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-table

How can I modify my code in order to have this picture. I tried using `max-h-full` and `max-w-full` but it's not working. I want a blue background for these 3 headers : "id","Taste", "Price". "Title" has no background color

Here my picture: [image]

```
import Table from "./Table";
import React from "react";
import JsonData from "./menus.json";

export default function Display() {
  const { menus } = JsonData;
  const data = [
    {
      Header: "id",
      accessor: (row) => row.id
    },
    {
      Header: "Taste",
      accessor: (row) => row.taste
    },
     ...
    {
      Header: "Title",
      accessor: (row) => row.title
    }
  ];
  return (
    <Table
      data={menus}
      columns={data}
      withCellBorder
      withRowBorder
      withSorting
      withPagination
    />
  );
}
```

[Table.jsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-leftpad-myego5?file=/src/Table.jsx)

Comment: Show the container of `my_data`

Comment: @morne, I've added this info in the issue

Comment: I've tried to look at your demo but it doesn't compile. Also, did you check the styling of the `th`?

Comment: @LiorPollak I've fixed that, and no I don't know what is th

Comment: Can you add your color to the demo? I can't see any color at all now